# How does open.spotify to detect mobile browser

Tags: android, redirect, browser, spotify

If you log in at https://open.spotify.com with your mobile you will be redirect to https://www.spotify.com and if you click on the button "launch web player" you will be redirect too. It's impossible to get the access of this page with a mobile. I tried to change my user agent but it doesn't work.

I'd like to do this on my web application too but I don't know how spotify does. Lot of anwser on SO say to use regex to check the user agent but this will not working if I change my user agent.

Do you know how spotify can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Detecting browser's details:

```
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}
// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
 fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
 majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}

document.write(''
 +'Browser name  = '+browserName+'<br>'
 +'Full version  = '+fullVersion+'<br>'
 +'Major version = '+majorVersion+'<br>'
 +'navigator.appName = '+navigator.appName+'<br>'
 +'navigator.userAgent = '+navigator.userAgent+'<br>'
)
```

Source [JavaScript: browser name](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browsern.htm).
See [JSFiddle to detect Browser Details](http://jsfiddle.net/q7tsm/).

Detecting OS:

```
// This script sets OSName variable as follows:
// "Windows"    for all versions of Windows
// "MacOS"      for all versions of Macintosh OS
// "Linux"      for all versions of Linux
// "UNIX"       for all other UNIX flavors 
// "Unknown OS" indicates failure to detect the OS

var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

Source [JavaScript: OS detection](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm).
See [JSFiddle to detect OS Details](http://jsfiddle.net/y26Zx/).

```js
    var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
    var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
    var browserName  = navigator.appName;
    var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
    var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
    var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;
    
    // In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
    if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Opera";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
     if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
       fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
    }
    // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Chrome";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
    }
    // In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Safari";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
     if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
       fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
    else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
     browserName = "Firefox";
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
    }
    // In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
    else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
              (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
    {
     browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
     fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
     if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
      browserName = navigator.appName;
     }
    }
    // trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
    if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
       fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
    if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
       fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
    
    majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
    if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
     fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
     majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
    }
    
    document.write(''
     +'Browser name  = '+browserName+'<br>'
     +'Full version  = '+fullVersion+'<br>'
     +'Major version = '+majorVersion+'<br>'
     +'navigator.appName = '+navigator.appName+'<br>'
     +'navigator.userAgent = '+navigator.userAgent+'<br>'
    )

    // This script sets OSName variable as follows:
    // "Windows"    for all versions of Windows
    // "MacOS"      for all versions of Macintosh OS
    // "Linux"      for all versions of Linux
    // "UNIX"       for all other UNIX flavors 
    // "Unknown OS" indicates failure to detect the OS
    
    var OSName="Unknown OS";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
    
    document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```